# Oracle functions are really slow with more schemas

Tags: database, oracle, function, schema

I am trying to describe my problem. We got two databases: a test db for developing and a production db. All tables, views, packages, functions, triggers etc. are the same on both databases. Both dbs structure and content should be same but somehow in some parts they works differently.

Test DB.

- Schema1 / Package1/Function1
- Schema2 / Package2/Procedure1

---

Prod. DB.

- Schema1 / Package1/Function1
- Schema2 / Package2/Procedure1
- Schema2 / Package1/Function1 <--emergency solution atm: absolutely same code,
  just moved from Schema 1 to Schema 2

---

In Test DB. Schema2/Package2/Procedure1 calls Schema1/Package1/Function1. It works fine (some seconds).

In Prod DB. Schema2/Package2/Procedure1 calls Schema1/Package1/Function1. It works really slow. (more minutes)

In Prod DB Schema2/Package2/Procedure1 calls Schema2/Package1/Function1. It works same fast.

Where should we check the problem in Prod DB.? What settings can be wrong in ini file or somewhere else?

Any ideas?

Comment: You may be better off asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - this appears to not be a specific programming question so is considered off-topic here.

Comment: These weird probably are usually the result of the SQL statements inside the PL/SQL.  You'll probably need to find the slow SQL statement and troubleshoot it.  There are plenty of unusual features, like cardinality feedback and adaptive cursor sharing, that can make SQL statements run slower or faster after a few executions.  Changing even the spacing of the SQL, or recompiling, may force Oracle to re-parse the statement and generate a new plan for some users.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a top-down approach.  Are Test DB and Prod DB on different servers?  If so, is it possible one server is more heavily loaded than the other?  (Look at top, sar, etc, to get an idea of overall system resources and how they're being used.)

Second, at the database level, Oracle is well-instrumented to help you determine root cause of any performance problem.  Step one, do you have the same execution plans in test and prod?  If the execution plan varies (and it can, based on data volume and data distribution, among other things), that could make a *huge* difference in performance.  (Use dbms_xplan to display the execution plans.)

If the execution plans don't differ, you should also consider if differences in data volumes and distributions may cause worse performance in prod, even with identical execution plans.

Finally, you could use a tool like Tanel Poder's snapper.sql (http://blog.tanelpoder.com/files/scripts/snapper.sql), to see exactly where time is being spent.  This could lead you to the root cause of your performance problem.

The nature of your question is such that there's really no specific answer.  I just tried to get you pointed in the right direction, and give you some points to think about.